# SAM create new role and new policy

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-sam

I am trying to create a new role and  a new policy which would be attached 
 to the same role created in the template in the same  template and getting 
 this error:

## Error:

> **Missing required field Principal(Service:AmazonIdentityManagement;
>
> Status Code: 400;
> Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument;
> Proxy: null)**

```
Resources:
  lambdaFullPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: "*"
            Resource: "*"
  LambdaFullRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version : '2012-10-17'
        Statement :
        - Effect : Allow
        - Principal :
            service :
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
        - Action :
          - sts: AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - !Ref lambdaFullPolicy
    DependsOn:
    - lambdaFullPolicy



  #------------------------------output -----------------------#

Outputs:
  PolicyFullLambda:
    Description: table
    Value: !Ref lambdaFullPolicy
    Export:
      Name:
        "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-PolicyFullLambda"
  RollFullLambda:
    Value: !Ref LambdaFullRole
    Export:
      Name:
        "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-RollFullLambda"
```

Comment: What is `AmazonIdentityManagement`?

Comment: ignore it .after I received error "Missing required field Principal (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement", I added it to the list of services. I know there is no aws service with that name.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean? If its not used, why its in your question? This makes your question hard to answer. What other aspects of it should be "ignored"?

Comment: I removed it and now it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra space in `sts: AssumeRole` and it should read `sts:AssumeRole`. This is because this is not a YAML component, but a string literal that AWS uses for the `Action` section of the Role creation/update.